# php using foreach in an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I want to use foreach in an array and this foreach uses an array. The code is here:

```
$records["data"][] = array(
  $id,
$value['name'],
foreach($kichen_organ as $x => $x_value){  if($value['organ']==$x) '<span class="badge badge-success">'echo $x_value;'</span>' },
$value['type'] ,
$value['name_responsible'] ,
$value['family_responsible'] ,
$value['office'],
$value['fax'],
$value['mobile']);
```

$kichen_organ is another array that I parse it's key and value by renaming $x and $s_value
but I received this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ')' in /var/www/html/...
```

What's the solution for using the loop in array?

Comment: You can add the elements to array after array declaration right?

Comment: what is this 'echo $x_value;' , in foreach , concatenation and foreach loop in array element ?

Comment: @Thamilan I add them in array declaration not after that

Comment: You're trying to echo a string as an element in an array ...?
You've mixed up the code - and there's must be a better way of achieving your goal. Let's start by understanding what's your end goal?

Comment: @OfirBaruch The goal is clear. I want to print some thing by using if for an element

Comment: @AmirHavangi The goal is not clear. You've put a `foreach` an `if` and an `echo` statement inside an array declaration

Comment: @developerCK This is the value of another array that it's name is $kichen_organ

Comment: Put the loop outside of the array and reference to it using a variable.

Comment: Not clear at all... what's $x? What's $kichen_organ? why do you have a foreach as an element in an array? Please elaborate regarding the logic and target you're aiming to achieve. Otherwise, how can we help you?

Answer (score 0):

```
$temp = [];

foreach($kichen_organ as $x => $x_value) {
    if ($value['organ'] == $x) {
        $temp[] = '<span class="badge badge-success">'.$x_value.'</span>';
    };
}

$records["data"][] = array_merge($temp,
    [
        $id,
        $value['name'],
        $value['type'] ,
        $value['name_responsible'] ,
        $value['family_responsible'] ,
        $value['office'],
        $value['fax'],
        $value['mobile']
    ]);
```

Comment: I received the error:  syntax error, unexpected '$x_value' (T_VARIABLE)